# Lat Long From GPS Tracker URL

Tags: url, gps, tracker

i have a gps tracker, model: GPS TRACKER GF21. i send the message 999 to receive the location, and it returns to me the real device location, like this:
BAT=84%,http://www.08gps.com/gps.php?x=Xq3XX3nccngn23g?zq=FzFFgz&?F3=zcXt3X

But, how can i get the lat long from this url? i want to store it in my database.
another example of gps responses.

1 - BAT=23%,http://www.08gps.com/wlbs.php?x=Xq3XX3nccngn23gvzxnXziFgqXFi3Fqqzyzg2&wifi=1?61?308550516084435037&2?70?16188184709064944

2 - BAT=99%,http://www.08gps.com/wlbs.php?x=Xq3XX3nccngn23gvvyfXziFgqFzcX3FFrX2zzn&wifi=1?75?160907828724115569&2?75?168220145604241521

3 - BAT=86%,http://www.08gps.com/gps.php?x=Xq3XX3nccngn23g?zq=FXnXzc&?F3=z23cqq

Comment: Here is a repository of GPS tracker protocols, however none seem to match the strings you are seeing:  https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B9QofkYKWsMuZnIwZ1BqeXhzQlE I have a similar tracker and have questioned the vendor, no answer yet.

Comment: hello thank you, i have done the same with the vendor, no answer tiil today. if you get the protocol please share with me. thank you.

Comment: Vendor did answer that the protocol was proprietary (i.e. secret), moreover it does not seem simple to reverse engineer. I have tried various encode/decode functions on the part that does change slightly when the position is moved and I did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has this question, the latitude, longitude, and IMEI are encoded in the URI using a very rudimentary cipher.

```
x=Xq3XX3nccngn23g?zq=FzFFgz&?F3=zcXt3X
  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIAAAAAAAAAA OOOOOOOOOO
  359339077010891-25.424412 -49.273693

where I = IMEI, A = latitude, O = longitude

The cipher is [ngzXFqtc23=?] => [01234567890.-]
```

which puts you in Curitiba Brazil.

Comment: can you tell me how to calculate to get this values?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to lack of reputation, but adding to the answer by TwoRedCells, here is some php to do the decode:

```
<?php

function decypher($s)
{
    $k = "ngzXFqtc23=?";
    $v = "0123456789.-";
    $result = '';
    for ($c = 0; $c < strlen($s); ++$c) {
        $result .= $v[strpos($k, $s[$c])];
    }
    return $result;
}

$i = "Xq3XX3ncqF2qtFXqz=cq3gtn&?g=F2gXgq"; // <==== Put your string here 

$imei = substr($i, 0, 15);
list($lat, $lon) = explode('&', substr($i, 15));

$imei = decypher($imei);
$lat = decypher($lat);
$lon = decypher($lon);

echo "imei=$imei\nlat=$lat\nlon=$lon\n";

echo "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/$lat/$lon\n"
```

When run in the console you get:

```
imei=359339075485643
lat=52.759160
lon=-1.481315
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/52.759160/-1.481315
```